# setFullYear does not set hours/min/sec of the Date object

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have code which will find how many seconds/minutes/hours/months/years since you were born. However I just noticed that the actual date object does not register the hours/minutes/seconds I input, and instead just uses the hours/minutes/seconds of the current date.

Here is the part where I set the `Date()` object:

```
theDate.setFullYear(y, m, d, h, m1, s);
```

And here is the full code (excuse the way it looks, it's just the small window JSFiddle gives you)
http://jsfiddle.net/LaCUh/

Just type in a date in the past, then look at the black text in the bottom left corner.

Any ideas how can I make it work?

Thanks,
Fjpackard.

Comment: Imagine that .. [`setFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) *doesn't* accept a time component. Please refer to the API.

Comment: It says it does here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Comment: ["Don't use w3schools"](http://www.w3fools.com/). However, the link provided does *not* show the usage the post does - so you can't even blame w3schools here.

Comment: It actually says "How to use setFullYear() to set a specific date.", there is no mention of time. I'm not endorsing w3schools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the function `setFullYear` only accepts parameters for year, month and day.
You can use the methods `setHour`, `setMinute` and `setSecond`.

```
theDate.setHours(h);
theDate.setMinutes(m1);
theDate.setSeconds(s);
```

Alternatively you could use the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
theDate = new Date(y, m, d, h, m1, s);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just updating my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately both of those solutions made it returned "Invalid Date", and I previously posted another question asking how to stop that. If you have any more ideas for a way to fix it please let me know.

Comment: Update the fiddle and I'll have another look.

Comment: Replacing the line `theDate.setFullYear(y, m, d, h, m1, s);` with `theDate = new Date(y, m, d, h, m1, s);` works wonderfully for me in chrome.

Comment: Can you please update the Fiddle with your code? Because I have tried what you said (I also use Chrome) and it's not working for me.

Comment: Tried it, still getting the same error ("Invalid Date") and all the values that use that date still return "NaN"

Comment: Strange. What values are you entering?

Comment: Just for testing I was using year 2000, month 9, day 11, and hour 5.
Also sometimes minute 44

Comment: Ok - In that case it's obvious - You're not providing all the data the function needs. I updated the fiddle and added a check whether the data is `NaN` and if yes, set a default value. You might want to modify those. http://jsfiddle.net/LaCUh/3/

Comment: Wow! Thanks very much :D  Working perfectly.